# Any problems if we test every things on E2E?

Tags: testing, end-to-end

I'm working on Flutter a project. We've test cases on the server-side.

On the client-side, We have an idea to only test every acceptance criteria on the E2E level?

The question is

What're the problems we will encounter after it's getting bigger?

Comment: "Is it a good idea" is not an answerable question.  We don't know what "good" means to you.  The phrase "best practice" has the same problem.

Comment: i've edited the question.

Comment: So... What are your possible alternatives?  Your question states "We have an idea to only test every acceptance criteria on the E2E level," which suggests that you have some motivator or underlying reason for considering that approach.  What is that motivator?

Comment: We write test only once, We and having higher confident than other kind of tests.

Comment: Is your question "we only want to test end-to-end," or "we only want to test acceptance criteria?"

Comment: We only want to do E2E test based on Acceptance criteria case and more edges cases if we found one. Assume that acceptance criteria was reliable.

Comment: Alright.  Well Jacob got it right; *end-to-end tests are brittle.*  I use them mostly for three reasons: 1.  I don't have time to write a comprehensive test suite, 2.  I need a "sanity check" on my code, a "smoke test," if you will, and 3.  I need to throw a lot of data at the entire stack to see if it breaks anywhere.  These kinds of tests are not actually proof that your software works, but they are better than nothing.

Comment: Why this question having so much down vote, I happy to improve but I really don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E2E tests are:

- *Brittle* - require frequent changes to many tests because of changes in a single piece of code, since each test exercises lots of code
- *Unreliable* - depend on many systems, which may not even be in your control, to be online and in an expected state
- *Slow* - take a long time to run because they do a lot of things
- *Late* - cannot be run immediately after coding a change, because that change must be deployed (and may also require changes to other systems first)
- *Undiagnostic* - tell you that *some* part of the chain broke, but often not *which* part

Why are E2E tests more brittle and unreliable, and does it matter? Suppose that there is a 99% chance that each piece of code works as before, and a 99% chance that each sub-system is in expected condition. Each test needs all concerned code and each system interacted with to work as expected. It only takes 10 links in such a chain to hit 90%, and 90% reliable tests are about as good as "it works on my machine". You certainly can't use them for hands-off deployment or incident reporting.

Why does it matter that E2E tests are slow, late and undiagnostic? The sooner you find an error, the cheaper it is to fix. If it can be found *immediately*, whoever made it is still in the right state of mind to fix it, and it is virtually free. If it is found after other systems have been accommodated to the erroneous behavior, it is *not* free.

---

Tests which exercise all of your code can also be a good thing. After all, you may have written "perfect" parts which do not interact well. If you have an otherwise untested system, they may be the best place to start in order to build up *some* confidence and understanding. *Simple* E2E tests ("smoke tests") can be a decent source of alerts if you can't get "proper" monitoring of sub-systems. But because of these shortcomings, you should mainly use other types of tests if you are actively working on a piece of software.

Comment: So, basically you're saying that end-to-end tests are brittle, right?

Comment: @RobertHarvey they are brittle in at least two senses, will often fail to indicate what went wrong, and provide a slow feedback loop